# How to access dynamically generated web content from App?

Tags: javascript, android, html

Trying to pull information from a web page for use in a Android app.  It looks like the information (song title) is dynamically added to the source.  In the source there's get a placeholder (using a  tag).  The browser, of course, displays the proper song title.

Looking for direction on how to go about getting my hands on that dynamically generated information in my app.

Thanks,

-- Joel

Comment: Are you trying to get the data from a webpage generated by the webapp? Or do you have access to the webapp's source code and want to modify it? Or is there an API? If the former, then you're probably looking at scraping the page and getting the field information out. Details would be very useful.

Comment: Basically: the webapp plays music from a radio station and shows the name of the current song and some other relevant information.  This information is updated as the music changes, obviously.  I am simply trying to get my hands on the name of the song currently playing (or whenever the app requests refreshment).

Comment: *"Whenever the app requests refreshment"* -- Great, so we're not just worried about machines **making** breakfast, now they're **asking** for breakfast too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first figure out how the information is obtained. I'd say it's most likely fetched using AJAX via Javascript. Take a look at that script.

Once you figure that out, you can reproduce the behavior of the script (requesting the proper address, same method/parameters, etc.) from your Java code.

If that's impossible (or impractical -- the script is obfuscated, for example), you could always (although this is kinda hacky and I would not recommend it) load the URL in a WebView and hook yourself to the appropiate AJAX request using the WebView's java interface; or have it load and retrieve the information after the request is complete.

Comment: How can I learn to identify the script being called from the HTML?

Comment: @Boswell - the javascript code is included from within the HTML (it is client side, after all). You can have an easier time if you use Chrome's built-in developer tools, or Firebug for Firefox, among others.

Comment: @birryree Thanks, the Chrome dev. tools led me to a token card that contains the info I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The song data MIGHT be embedded in the audio stream, in which case your decoder/player would have to be able to extract that info.

Comment: At this point my software isn't interested in the audio, just the meta data.  What would be less expensive: loading the audio steam or loading the web page and parsing that?

Comment: The web page, assuming that it doesn't just monitor the audio stream and set the song title/etc via javascript.  The benefit of monitoring the audio stream would be the ability to display the "new" song data as soon as it starts playing, rather than as soon as you scrape the web page.